# Class member access in Python Dash apps and callbacks

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I need help to understand some fundamental workings of a Python `Dash` app.

Since I need to implement a quite complicated application as a `Dash` app, I came up with a basic interface for my components.

```
class IComponent:
    def __init__(self, app:Dash, baseId:str) -> None:
        self._app = app
        self._id = baseId
        self._component = None

    def setup(self):
        """The calling scope will call this function to get the actual component to be added to the Dash layout."""
        self._create()
        self._registerCallbacks()
        return self._component

    def _create(self)
        """Implementation will create the Dash component and assign it to the self._component member."""
        raise NotImplementedError

    def _registerCallbacks(self):
        """Implementation will define all necessary callbacks for the component. Necessary component ids for interaction with other components may be passed to the implementation's constructor."""
        raise NotImplementedError
```

An implementation for a very simple component, e.g. a modal asking the user for a text input, would look like this:

```
class TextInputModal(IComponent):
    def __init__(self, app:Dash, baseId:str, o_storeText:str, t_openTrigger:str):
        super().__init__(app, baseId)
        self.o_storeText = o_storeText       # this is the id of a Store component to which the user text should be stored
        self.t_openTrigger = t_openTrigger   # this is the id to a button that triggers the modal

    def _create(self):
        header = dbc.ModalHeader("Provide Input")
        body = dbc.ModalBody(dbc.Input(id=self._id+"input"))
        footer = dbc.ModalFooter(dbc.Button(id=self._id+"confirm", children="Confirm"))
        modal = dbc.Modal(id=self._id, children=[header, body, footer], is_open=False)
        self._component = modal

    def _registerCallbacks(self):
        app = self._app
        id = self._id
        @app.callback(
            [Output(id, "is_open")],
            [Input(self.t_openTrigger, "n_clicks"),
             Input(id+"confirm", "n_clicks")],
            [State(id, "is_open"],
            prevent_initial_callback=True
        )
        def setVisibility(_, _, isOpen:bool):
            return not IsOpen

        @app.callback(
            [Output(self.o_storeText, "data")],
            [Input(id+"confirm", "n_clicks")],
            [State(id+"input", "value"],
            prevent_initial_callback=True
        )
        def setVisibility(text:str):
            return text
```

The calling scope would instantiate the `TextInputModal`, pass the necessary arguments `textInputModel = TextInputModal(...)`, especially the component ids it depends on and then add it to a Dash layout (or another component's children) by calling the `textInputModal.setup()` method.

This way allows for better structure of my modules, code separation, avoiding code duplication etc. For further improvement of this approach I need to know:

1. Can I use `IComponent` class members in my callbacks? (Other than I already successfully do to just assign ids and initialize callbacks!) I'm more thinking about e.g. putting some data into a class member, which is accessed by a callback to draw a plot upon a trigger. Or is this just a hidden violation of the "no globals" rule?
2. How does the answer to (1.) change, if my Dash app is only used by ONE user locally (localhost)?
3. How can I think of the very fundamental flow in a Dash app (assume I am a total beginner)? Where are Outputs/Inputs created (server/localhost, browser?)? What part of a callback is server-side, which one is client-side? Which data is shared between clients etc.? Where do callbacks "live" (think of my member variable question...) etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. That would be a violation of the "no globals" rule.
2. It doesn't. You are still not guarantee that your app will work as intended. It might work. Sometimes. But I wouldn't rely on it.
3. Callbacks are executed server-side (unless you use a client-side callback, then it is executed client-side). The server-side of Dash is stateless, so data is not shared between clients (unless you do it explicitly, e.g. via a shared cache). Hence you must keep state client side (e.g. in a `Store` element), or use a separate server-side state store (files on disk, a Redis cache, etc.).

Comment: Thank you! @2: What mechanisms in the dash framework would modify class members it does not even know about? It is a no-brainer that (2) is not allowed with more clients, but when I use it as a desktop app....? @3: If you are aware of the `dash-extensions` `ServersideOutput` transform for `Store` elements --> it keeps the data server-side. So let's say I put a big numpy array in such a server-side store, then I plot it. Which JSON serialization "transmissions" are saved? Thanks!